# How to store multiple values from star ratings using Jquery Raty in Rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I am building an application where users are able to rate a **Listing** based on a set of criteria.

I want the users to be able to rate each attribute 1-5 stars.

Example:
Location (1-5 stars)
Value For the money (1-5 stars)
etc..

I currently have a simple form that looks like this.

```
<%= simple_form_for([@stadium, @rating]) do |f| %>

<label>Rate the Location:</label>
<div class="rating-location">
</div>


<label>Rate the value for the money:</label>
<div class="rating-monetary-value">
</div>

...

<div class="actions">
  <%= f.button :submit,  "Submit Rating", class:'btn btn-success' %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

```
<script>
  $('.rating-location').raty({
    path: '/assets/',
    scoreName: 'rating[location]',
    hints: ['bad', 'poor', 'regular', 'good', 'gorgeous']
    });
</script>
```

This saves the location-rating to the location-column in my **Ratings** Table.

But I'm not sure how I should proceed in order to save more than 1 value to the same table. Eg the monetary-value ratings, and the other rating attributes). In total there are 8 different attributes that the user can rate.

I'm new to Rails and Jquery and trying to learn. Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I had an issue similar to yours. My workaround is to create separate id for each attribute and create separate raty call in js script. So in your case:

```
<label>Rate the Location:</label>
 <div id="rating-location"></div>

<label>Rate the Monetary Value:</label>
<div id="rating-monetary-value"></div>

<script>
  $('#rating-location').raty({
    path: '/assets/',
    scoreName: 'rating[location]',
    hints: ['bad', 'poor', 'regular', 'good', 'gorgeous']
  });

  $('#rating-monetary-value').raty({
    path: '/assets/',
    scoreName: 'rating[monatery-value]',
    hints: ['bad', 'poor', 'regular', 'good', 'gorgeous']
  });
</script>
```

This seems like a lot of code duplication (I have around 10 attributes), but it works for now.

You could also use the gem "ratyrate" where it'll let you specify each attribute in the model: https://github.com/wazery/ratyrate